# Get row indices of data frame A according to multiple matching criteria in that data frame and another data frame, B

Tags: r, matching

Let's say we have two data frames in R, `df.A` and `df.B`, defined thus:

```
bin_name <- c('bin_1','bin_2','bin_3','bin_4','bin_5')
bin_min <- c(0,2,4,6,8)
bin_max <- c(2,4,6,8,10)
df.A <- data.frame(bin_name, bin_min, bin_max, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

obs_ID <- c('obs_1','obs_2','obs_3','obs_4','obs_5','obs_6','obs_7','obs_8','obs_9','obs_10')
obs_min <- c(6.5,0,8,2,1,7,5,6,8,3)
obs_max <- c(7,3,10,3,9,8,5.5,8,10,4)
df.B <- data.frame(obs_ID, obs_min, obs_max, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

`df.A` defines the ranges of bins, while `df.B` consists of rows of observations with min and max values that may or may not fall entirely within a bin defined in `df.A`.

We want to generate a new vector of length `nrow(df.B)` containing the row indices of `df.A` corresponding to the bin in which each observation falls entirely. If an observation straddles a bin falls or partially outside it, then it can't be assigned to a bin and should return `NA` (or something similar).

In the above example, the correct output vector would be this:

```
bin_rows <- c(4, NA, 5, 2, NA, 4, 3, 4, 5, 2)
```

I came up with a long-winded solution using `sapply`:

```
bin_assignments <- sapply(1:nrow(df.B), function(i) which(df.A$bin_max >= df.B$obs_max[i] & df.A$bin_min <= df.B$obs_min[i])) #get bin assignments for every observation
bin_assignments[bin_assignments == "integer(0)"] <- NA #replace "integer(0)" entries with NA
bin_assignments <- do.call("c", bin_assignments) #concatenate the output of the sapply call
```

Several months ago I discovered a simple, single-line solution to this problem that didn't use an apply function. However, I forgot how I did this and I have not been able to rediscover it! The solution might involve `match()` or `which()`. Any ideas?

Comment: If anyone can think of a more concise and descriptive title to this question, please suggest one!

Comment: Are the bins consecutive integer ranges? You could compare `findInterval(df.B$obs_min, seq(0, 10, 2))` with `findInterval(df.B$obs_max, seq(0, 10, 2), rightmost.closed = TRUE, left.open = TRUE)` and replace with `NA` in case of inequality.

Comment: Bins are not *always* consecutive interval ranges, although bins never overlap. Thanks for the suggestion, though. I haven't used findInterval before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Using SQL it can readily be done in one statement:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf('select a.rowid
       from "df.B" b 
       left join "df.A" a on obs_min >= bin_min and obs_max <= bin_max')

   rowid
1      4
2     NA
3      5
4      2
5     NA
6      4
7      3
8      4
9      5
10     2
```

**2) merge/by**  We can do it in two statements using `merge` and `by`.  No packages are used.

This does have the downside that it materializes the large join which the SQL solution would not need to do.

Note that `df.B`, as defined in the question, has `obs_10` is the second level rather than the 10th level.  If it were such that `obs_10` were the 10th level then the second argument to `by` could have been just `m$obs_ID` so fixing up the input first could simplify it.

```
m <- merge(df.B, df.A)
stack(by(m, as.numeric(sub(".*_", "", m$obs_ID)), 
      with, c(which(obs_min >= bin_min & obs_max <= bin_max), NA)[1]))
```

giving:

```
   values ind
1       4   1
2      NA   2
3       5   3
4       2   4
5      NA   5
6       4   6
7       3   7
8       4   8
9       5   9
10      2  10
```

**3) sapply** Note that using the `c(..., NA)[1]` trick from (2) we can simplify the `sapply` solution in the quesiton to one statement:

```
sapply(1:nrow(df.B), function(i)
  c(which(df.A$bin_max >= df.B$obs_max[i] & df.A$bin_min <= df.B$obs_min[i]), NA)[1])
```

giving:

```
[1]  4 NA  5  2 NA  4  3  4  5  2
```

**3a) mapply** A nicer variation of (3) using `mapply` is given by @Ronak Shah` in the comments:

```
mapply(function(x, y) c(which(x >= df.A$bin_min & y <= df.A$bin_max), NA)[1], 
       df.B$obs_min, 
       df.B$obs_max)
```

**4) outer**  Here is another one statement solution that uses no packages.

```
seq_len(nrow(df.A)) %*% 
  (outer(df.A$bin_max, df.B$obs_max, ">=") & outer(df.A$bin_min, df.B$obs_min, "<="))
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    4    0    5    2    0    4    3    4    5     2
```

Comment: These are all really neat solutions containing clever and useful tricks; thanks! However, I'm going to wait a bit to if someone comes up with the solution that I discovered and lost before accepting your answer.

Comment: Added solution (4)

Comment: That one's also great, and seems much faster than the sapply solution. It's not the solution I found, but I'll accept your answer.

Comment: and similar with `mapply` , `t(mapply(function(x, y) c(which(x >= df.A$bin_min & y <= df.A$bin_max), NA)[1], df.B$obs_min, df.B$obs_max))`